# How can I open a window first, instead of a MainWindow in WPF (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, visual-studio

So, when I click start debugging it's showing my mainwindow instead of another window, which is what I wanted to test.

Here is the main window code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml;
using EasyExploits;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using MeguSploit;

namespace Exploit_Template
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        Module m = new Module();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
                this.DragMove();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (StreamReader s = new StreamReader("./Bin/Languages/Lua.xshd"))
            {
                using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(s))
                {
                    TextEditor.SyntaxHighlighting = ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Highlighting.Xshd.HighlightingLoader.Load(reader, HighlightingManager.Instance);
                }
            }

            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("./Scripts");
            FileInfo[] f = di.GetFiles("*.txt");
            foreach (FileInfo fi in f)
            {
                ListBox.Items.Add(fi.Name);
            }

            DirectoryInfo din = new DirectoryInfo("./Scripts");
            FileInfo[] file = din.GetFiles("*.lua");
            foreach (FileInfo fil in file)
            {
                ListBox.Items.Add(fil.Name);
            }
        }

        private void Exit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }

        private void Minimize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        }

        private void Load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ListBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                TextEditor.Text = File.ReadAllText($"./Scripts/{ListBox.SelectedItem}");
            }
        }

        private void Refresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox.Items.Clear();

            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("./Scripts");
            FileInfo[] f = di.GetFiles("*.txt");
            foreach (FileInfo fi in f)
            {
                ListBox.Items.Add(fi.Name);
            }

            DirectoryInfo din = new DirectoryInfo("./Scripts");
            FileInfo[] file = din.GetFiles("*.lua");
            foreach (FileInfo fil in file)
            {
                ListBox.Items.Add(fil.Name);
            }
        }

        private void ExecuteL_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ListBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                m.ExecuteScript(File.ReadAllText($"./Scripts/{ListBox.SelectedItem}"));
            }
        }

        private void Execute_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            m.ExecuteScript(TextEditor.Text);
            Status.Content = "Executed!";
        }

        private void Clear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextEditor.Text = "";
            Status.Content = "Ready!";
        }

        private void OpenFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Txt Files (*.txt)|*.txt|Lua Files (*.lua)|*.lua";
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                TextEditor.Text = File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName);
            }
        }

        private void ExecuteFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ef = new OpenFileDialog();
            ef.Filter = "Txt Files (*.txt)|*.txt|Lua Files (*.lua)|*.lua";
            if (ef.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                m.ExecuteScript(ef.FileName);
            }
        }

        private void SaveFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Filter = "Txt Files (*.txt)|*.txt|Lua Files (*.lua)|*.lua";
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                File.WriteAllText(sfd.FileName, TextEditor.Text);
            }
        }

        private void Attach_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            m.LaunchExploit();
            Status.Content = "Injected!";
        } 

        private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

And here is the window that I will like to start first.

```
using Exploit_Template;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace MeguSploit
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start("https://shrinkme.io/BWe0");
        }

        private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Pass.Text == new WebClient().DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/VTGJqX6k") || Pass.Text == "stefanradu2005eadminsiesmekrau")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Thank you for using MeguSploit");
                this.Hide();
                MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
                main.Show();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry the key is invalid", "Key Invalid");
            }
        }

        private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
                this.DragMove();
        }
    }
}
```

I really need help, I am new in the programming world. Thanks in advance. Also I don't want to take it all from the beginning because I will waste alot of time. That will be the last option.

Comment: change Application.Run(new MainWindow ()); toyour form in program.cs

Comment: @mehdifarhadi that should be an answer, not a comment ;)

Comment: @mehdifarhadi Actually he is in a WPF application not in a winform so for the entry point he should use the `App.g.cs` but is more easy change the `StartupUri` inside the App.xaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `StartupUri` in the App.xaml , from MainWindow.xaml to Window1.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

</Application>
```

See also the relative [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.startupuri?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Visual Studio 2015-2019: By default the template for creating WPF Applications specifies the StartupUri in the App.xaml. Change it to your Window file.